# "HTTP Authorization failure" building Liferay portlet in Eclipse

Tags: ant, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

Here is my `build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>

<project name="build-common-portlet">
    <import file="../build-common-plugin.xml" />
</project>
```

I am using Liferay portlet in Eclipse. When I run build.xml as an Ant build it fails.

Here is the error trace:

```
Buildfile: G:\softwares\lifeRay_CMS\plugin\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\Sample-portlet\build.xml
  [get] Getting: http://mirrors.lax.liferay.com/cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-snapshots-ce/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  [get] To: C:\Users\user\.liferay\mirrors\cdn.repository.liferay.com\nexus\content\repositories\liferay-snapshots-ce\com\liferay\org.apache.ivy\2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT\org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  [get] Error getting http://mirrors.lax.liferay.com/cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-snapshots-ce/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\user\.liferay\mirrors\cdn.repository.liferay.com\nexus\content\repositories\liferay-snapshots-ce\com\liferay\org.apache.ivy\2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT\org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  [get] Getting: http://cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-snapshots-ce/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  [get] To: C:\Users\user\.liferay\mirrors\cdn.repository.liferay.com\nexus\content\repositories\liferay-snapshots-ce\com\liferay\org.apache.ivy\2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT\org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar

BUILD FAILED
G:\softwares\lifeRay_CMS\plugin\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\Sample-portlet\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
G:\softwares\lifeRay_CMS\plugin\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\build-common-portlet.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
G:\softwares\lifeRay_CMS\plugin\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-plugin.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
G:\softwares\lifeRay_CMS\plugin\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:60: The following error occurred while executing this line:
G:\softwares\lifeRay_CMS\plugin\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-ivy.xml:130: The following error occurred while executing this line:
G:\softwares\lifeRay_CMS\plugin\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-ivy.xml:81: HTTP Authorization failure
```

Comment: Show your error traces.

Comment: @ParkashKumar edited with error trace.

Comment: [***This***](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/74382032) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you need to check **build.[username].properties** file in liferay_plugins/build.myUser.properties.

First check if this is pointing the correct directory

```
app.server.parent.dir = ../liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6
```

Then change this:

```
ivy.version = 2.3.0  
ivy.jar.url =http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.version}/ivy-${ivy.version}.jar
```

This link is helpful [liferay 6.2 ivy problem](https://web.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/74382032)